# Converting Flat data to hierarchical

Tags: c#, recursion, hierarchical-data

I am getting some flat data in a c# application as a list.
Sample data [google drive spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Al4-6rdb1OavdEhqd2d3QjFHWmh2bjRtREJfdTZZUXc&usp=sharing)

I want this data to be converted into a hierarchical structure. Have created a JSON representation of the same [here](http://jsonblob.com/532a0837e4b055cb28536e5c)

The final structure I am expecting is here [image]

I have created the data as a list in C#. I want this list to be converted into a c# collection object. Please give me pointers on what will be easiest way to do so.
    [this is a console application code]

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{

    public class Marklist
    {

    public string Student_name { set; get; }
    public string Frequency  { set; get; }
    public string Major  { set; get; }
    public string Subject_category   { set; get; }
    public string Subject_subcategory { set; get; } 
    public int Spring_mark   { set; get; }
    public int Autumn_mark   { set; get; }
    public int Summer_mark { set; get; }



        public Marklist() { }

        public Marklist(string student_name,string frequency,string major,string        subject_category,string subject_subcategory,string spring_mark,string autumn_mark,string summer_mark)
        {

             Student_name =student_name;
             Frequency   =frequency;
              Major  =major;
               Subject_category  =subject_category;
              Subject_subcategory   =subject_subcategory;
            Spring_mark  =spring_mark;
            Autumn_mark  =autumn_mark;
            Summer_mark =summer_mark;

        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    List<Marklist> Marklists = new List<Marklist>();

        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Science",Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Atomic",Spring_mark=100,Autumn_mark=95,Summer_mark=75});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Science", Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Nuclear",Spring_mark=95, Autumn_mark=75,Summer_mark=100});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Science", Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Electronics",Spring_mark=75, Autumn_mark=95,Summer_mark=100});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Language", Subject_category="Tamil",Subject_subcategory="Literature",Spring_mark=80, Autumn_mark=90,Summer_mark=70});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Commerce" Subject_category="Retail_data",Subject_subcategory="Big_data_analytics",Spring_mark=90, Autumn_mark=80,Summer_mark=70});

        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Weekly",Major="Science",Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Atomic",Spring_mark=100,Autumn_mark=95,Summer_mark=75});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Weekly",Major="Science", Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Nuclear",Spring_mark=95, Autumn_mark=75,Summer_mark=100});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Weekly",Major="Science", Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Electronics",Spring_mark=75, Autumn_mark=95,Summer_mark=100});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Weekly",Major="Language", Subject_category="Tamil",Subject_subcategory="Literature",Spring_mark=80, Autumn_mark=90,Summer_mark=70});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="Nimalan",Frequency="Weekly",Major="Commerce" Subject_category="Retail_data",Subject_subcategory="Big_data_analytics",Spring_mark=90, Autumn_mark=80,Summer_mark=70});

        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="StarNimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Science",Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Atomic",Spring_mark=100,Autumn_mark=95,Summer_mark=75});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="StarNimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Science", Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Nuclear",Spring_mark=95, Autumn_mark=75,Summer_mark=100});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="StarNimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Science", Subject_category="Physics",Subject_subcategory="Electronics",Spring_mark=75, Autumn_mark=95,Summer_mark=100});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="StarNimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Language", Subject_category="Tamil",Subject_subcategory="Literature",Spring_mark=80, Autumn_mark=90,Summer_mark=70});
        Marklists.Add(new Marklist(){Student_name="StarNimalan",Frequency="Monthly",Major="Commerce" Subject_category="Retail_data",Subject_subcategory="Big_data_analytics",Spring_mark=90, Autumn_mark=80,Summer_mark=70});

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Only way I have done it in the past is loop through every line and continue to check my collections to see if an object already exists for the data I want to enter and either add or use the existing object if it existed or not. Then start looping through its collections using the same pattern and so on. I don't believe there is a quicker way, but would love to find out.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: As I can see you have already file with json format. So if you have the data already, you can make method that will load the data from json file into your application and add it into list<>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class created from your json data using jsonC# http://json2csharp.com/#

```
public class Mark
{
public string markname { get; set; }
public int mark { get; set; }
}

public class SubjectSubcategory
{
public string name { get; set; }
public List<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
}

public class SubjectCategory
{
public string name { get; set; }
public List<SubjectSubcategory> Subject_subcategory { get; set; }
}

 public class Major
{
public string name { get; set; }
public List<SubjectCategory> Subject_category { get; set; }
 }

 public class Frequency
 {
public string name { get; set; }
public List<Major> Major { get; set; }
 }

public class Product
{
public string studentname { get; set; }
 public List<Frequency> frequency { get; set; }
 }

public class RootObject
{
public List<Product> product { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First group by student name, this will give you a distinct record for each student with collection of rows of data. Then for each of these, group by frequency, then group by major and so on and on.